# Python program for iteration based on multiple criterias

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, data-processing, exceldatareader

i'm new to Python, need Experts support to get output 1 & output 2 based on attached Input
Can somebody help me to complete the below python code, need output 1 and Output 2 in separate sheets

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZH9A.png][Input]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZH9A.png%5D%5BInput%5D)

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfZOG.png[Output1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfZOG.png%5BOutput1%5D)

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbAGx.png[Output2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbAGx.png%5BOutput2%5D)

Thanks in advance

My current code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
Path = "C:\Input.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Path)
sheet1 = wb["Sample"]
if os.path.exists("C:\Output.xlsx"):
    os.remove("C:\Output.xlsx")
else:
    print("The file does not exist")
newbook = Workbook()
newbook["Sheet"].title = "Output1"
newbook.create_sheet("Output2")
newbook.save("C:\Output.xlsx")
ShtOut1 = newbook["Output1"]
ShtOut2 = newbook["Output2"]
mr1 = sheet1.max_row
mc1 = sheet1.max_column
for k in range(1, mr1 + 1):
    for l in range(2, 4):
        d = sheet1.cell(row=k, column=l)
        ShtOut1.cell(row=k, column=l-1).value = d.value
newbook.save("C:\Output.xlsx")
```